# Example of sample median of continuous random variable that does not converge almost surely

Tags: probability, probability-theory, weak-convergence

I am a bit stuck by the following:

The sample mean generally converges almost surely to the true value given some mild conditions on the distribution;

However, the sample median does not seem to converge almost surely but only in probability. This kind of amazes me, so I would like to know if anyone can give me an example of a continuous random variable $X$ which is normal in a sense such that let's say

$$-\infty < c_1<q_X(0.5-\epsilon)<q_X(0.5+\epsilon)=c_2<\infty$$

so the sample median is somewhat bounded in a finite interval but the sample median does still not converge almost surely..

Comment: Isn't it almost sure convergence because the empirical df is almost surely convergent and since the quantile is a continuous mapping, the median/quantile is itself a.s. convergent? (for a continous random variable)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you may be looking for something along the lines of the density $f(x)=\frac32x^2$ on $[-1,1]$.

Since $f(0)=0$, you cannot use Laplace's normal approximation. It seems that for odd sample sizes you get a bimodal distribution for the sample median.

For example, trying in R to look at a sample size of $1001$ with just over $10^5$ simulations , you get the following distribution for the median with a high probability of being  well away from $0$ (and larger sample sizes would only narrow the distribution slowly):

```
df <- function(x){ ifelse(x < -1,0, ifelse(x > 1,0, 
                   (3/2)*x^2 )) }
pf <- function(q){ ifelse(q < -1,0, ifelse(q > 1,1, 
                   (q^3+1)/2 )) }
qf <- function(p){ ifelse(p < 0,NA, ifelse(p > 1,NA, 
                   sign(2*p-1)*abs(2*p-1)^(1/3) )) }
rf <- function(n){ qf(runif(n)) }
med <- function(n){ median(rf(n)) }
set.seed(2021)
sims <- replicate(100001, med(1001))
summary(sims)
#       Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean    3rd Qu.       Max. 
# -0.5256199 -0.2777905  0.0377480  0.0004548  0.2777602  0.5325429    
plot(density(sims, bw=0.01), main="Simulated distribution of sample median")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Henry, thanks for your great efforts; In your example, it seems obvious that we get a bimodal distribution of the median (since the densitiy itself is symmetric and is 0 for x=0), however, I am surprised how far the median is away from 0; Just two questions 1. Only because it is bimodal, it does not mean that it does not converge almost surely, right? 2. What do you think about that question that I found in the meantime? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3100119/does-x-n-stackreld-to-x-and-y-n-to-0-almost-surely-imply-that-x-n-y-n

Comment: @Johannes - I am not certain whether this particular case converges almost surely (hence "My guess"), but it does illustrate that it is possible to have a surprisingly wide distribution for the median from a continuous bounded distribution despite a large sample size.  Further empirical investigation suggests that, for large odd samples, the interquartile range for the distribution of the median may be about $1.754 \,n^{-1/6}$.  I would expect there are other distributions with even slower convergence.